# Regex will quite if the first character does not match the pattern, even if there should be a match later

Tags: java, regex

I am using regex in java, and I cannot create a regex to match what I want it to. I want to match everything in a string that begins and ends with a character.

"cats-are-cute" should match and return cats-are-cute

!!!DOG-CAT!!! should match and return DOG-CAT

I am using https://regexr.com/ to test, and it says my regex should work

I'm not even sure how I should attempt to fix this. I've found out that it will quite if the very first character does not match (e.i it is a special character) but it will match if the entire string begins + ends with a matching character.

It will not match if a special character begins or ends the entire string

Here is my code:

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([A-Za-z0-9].*[A-Za-z0-9])");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(word);
    if(matcher.matches())
    {
        System.out.println("Matches");
        System.out.println(matcher.start());
        System.out.println(matcher.end());
    }
```

if I type 
`testing`
it returns

```
Matches
0
7
```

Small question: why is it 7 and not 6?

just like it should
but if I do "testing" matcher.matches() is false.
I think it should output

```
Matches
1
7
```

but sadly it does not as matcher.matches() returns false.
I think my regex is working, because quite a few sites have said that my regex will match what I want it to.
Am I missing something with Matcher matches()? Does it not do what I think it does?

Comment: As the documentation of `Matcher.matches` states it *Attempts to match the entire region against the pattern.*. You need to use `Matcher.find` if you don't want your entire String to be matched.

Comment: >.< dang I'm not very smart are I?
Edit: That worked, thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

I just needed to use find instead of matches, as [OH GOD SPIDERS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6073886/oh-god-spiders) suggested in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57911078/regex-will-quite-if-the-first-character-does-not-match-the-pattern-even-if-ther/57911198#comment102241765_57911078):

> As the documentation of `Matcher.matches` states it *Attempts to match the entire region against the pattern.*. You need to use `Matcher.find` if you don't want your entire String to be matched.